# Pasting text to VirtualBox FreeDOS

Tags: virtualbox, copy-paste, clipboard, freedos

I’m looking for an easy way to paste text from a Windows host machine to a VirtualBox VM running FreeDOS.

I’ve been mounting the VHD in Windows to move files, but this is not convenient to paste text snippets. Does anyone know of a way to get around the limitation of not having GA to paste plain text?

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to paste an entire file using `keyboardputfile`.  An excerpt from https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=80315&start=15#p414817:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <uuid|vmname>
                     keyboardputscancode <hex> [<hex> ...]
                     keyboardputstring <string1> [<string2> ...]
                     keyboardputfile <filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

All information I can find about VirtualBox shows that it does not have this ability. Which is strange, being it is nothing special to simulate keystrokes from the clipboard. Both Hyper-V and VMWare can do this without guest additions.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to send simple strings, you can use the `VBoxManage controlvm keyboardputstring` tool.

For example:

```bash
$ vboxmanage controlvm freedosvm keyboardputstring 'hello'
```

which'd essentially type "hello" into the VM for you, by issuing key-press key-release commands.

If you need to do anything more complicated like pressing key combinations, you can use the lower level `keyboardputscancode` interface:

```
$ vboxmanage controlvm freedosvm keyboardputscancode 1D 23 A3 9D
```

This'd type "ctrl-h". You have to manually manage modifier keys and both pressing and unpressing keys (1D is the hex scancode for press-left-ctrl, 23 is 'h', and a3 9d are the release scancodes for the same)

There's [documentation on IBM PC scancodes here](https://www.win.tue.nl/%7Eaeb/linux/kbd/scancodes-1.html).